# Spark SQL cannot REDUCE bigint array

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with databricks 8 with a Spark 3.1.1 cluster.
I have a temperatures column that holds and array of bigint, but I'm getting an error when I want process an average of the array with:

```
SELECT
temps,
REDUCE(temps, 0, (t, acc) -> t + acc, acc ->(acc div size(temps))) as avg_daily_temp_c
FROM data
```

This is the error:

> Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'aggregate(spark_catalog.default.device_part.`temps`, 0, lambdafunction((CAST(namedlambdavariable() AS BIGINT) + namedlambdavariable()), namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable()), lambdafunction((CAST(namedlambdavariable() AS BIGINT) div CAST(size(spark_catalog.default.device_part.`temps`) AS BIGINT)), namedlambdavariable()))' due to data type mismatch: argument 3 requires int type, however, 'lambdafunction((CAST(namedlambdavariable() AS BIGINT) + namedlambdavariable()), namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable())' is of bigint type.; line 2 pos 2;
> Project [temps#1855, aggregate(temps#1855, 0, lambdafunction((cast(lambda t#1857 as bigint) + lambda acc#1858L), lambda t#1857, lambda acc#1858L, false), lambdafunction((cast(lambda acc#1859 as bigint) div cast(size(temps#1855, true) as bigint)), lambda acc#1859, false)) AS avg_daily_temp_c#1842L, time#1856]
> +- SubqueryAlias spark_catalog.default.device_part
> +- Relation[battery_level#1850,co2_level#1851,p_device_id#1852L,device_type#1853,signal#1854,temps#1855,time#1856] parquet

With another column of array-int there are no problems at all with the same code. Any advice will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly cast types to prevent this sort of error:

```
SELECT
temps,
REDUCE(temps, cast(0 as bigint), (t, acc) -> cast(t as bigint) + cast(acc as bigint), acc -> (acc div size(temps))) as avg_daily_temp_c
FROM data
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `temps` is an array of `bigint`, you only need to cast the initial value to `bigint`:

```
SELECT
  temps,
  REDUCE(temps, cast(0 as bigint), (t, acc) -> t + acc, acc ->(acc div size(temps))) as avg_daily_temp_c
FROM data
```

Alternatively, instead of the [`reduce`](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/reduce.html) function, you can use the [`aggregate`](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/aggregate.html) function.